# Can´t use sequences/lists in YAML with Spring Cloud Config

Tags: spring, yaml, spring-cloud-config

I´m having problems using an (apparently) valid YML file with Spring Cloud Config as soon as I try to use anything like list or sequences.

Some dummy YML samples. This one works when I hit the endpoint exposed by the server:

```
info:
   description: "This is the collector for CEM"
   git-commit: "bla bla MD5"
   version: "0.2.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

This one does not work:

```
info:
   description: "This is the collector for CEM"
   git-commit: "bla bla MD5"
   version: "0.2.0-SNAPSHOT"
   items: [ "a", "b", "c"]
```

Tried this as well:

```
info:
   description: "This is the collector for CEM"
   git-commit: "bla bla MD5"
   version: "0.2.0-SNAPSHOT"
   items:
       - "a"
       - "b"
       - "c"
```

The error I get with the second and third examples is this one:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 462: StartTag: invalid element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

What would be the correct way of using lists/sequences? I am mostly interested in lists of complex objects and, unfortunately, the samples provided are almost always one-liners.

Cheers!

**Update**: I fixed a badly written example (the third one). I still does not work.

**Update 2**: This is actually an issue with the HTML renderer and not with the functionality of the config server itself, as it passes the config to the client without issue. However the HTML is a nice-to-have as it gives you visual information on what is being loaded.

**Update 3**: I´m using Spring Cloud Brixton.SR7

Comment: Actually, it's not only related to HTML renderer. Spring Cloud config client using Jackson XmlMapper also can't deserialize this (with exception: HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) excepted space, or '>' or "/>"). This is because of badly formatted XML with <node[0]> <node[1]> etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be removed pulling the latest version of Spring Cloud Config. However, now JSON is displayed instead of XML.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with:

```
items:
  - a
  - b
  - c
```

Comment: Hi barts, Sorry, the example was badly written. I used something like you showed and still does not work. Actually, I copy YML samples from the Spring documentation and still does not work :(